# Perform segue loses Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller

I have a `Show` type `UIStoryboardSegue` with `abSegue` identifier. It navigates from UIViewController `A` to `B`.

In the entire application I use custom UINavigationController which works perfectly fine, but here it doesn't.

Using `self.performSegue(id: "abSegue", sender: self)` causes loss of the `UINavigationController`, but using

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: bundle).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "B")
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller)
```

works fine and I receive expected `UINavigationController`.

What can cause that behaviour?

Comment: In your storyboard, is `A` the root VC of your Navigation Controller, or at least connected via segues to the Nav Controller?

Comment: @DonMag yes, it is

Comment: OK - and is the segue in your storyboard from `A` to `B` *also* in the Nav Controller hierarchy? And its "Kind" is `Show (e.g. Push)`?

Comment: This latest @DonMag question is maybe the key here... You might want to give us a quick overview of how UINavigationController → is linked to A → is linked to B... Maybe by providing a screenshot of your storyboard. Segues can be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueID, sender: self)
```

Comment: I use Swift version 3.3

Comment: this is exactly what the asker is doing, so this doesn't really answer their question

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the `UIViewController` like so:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: bundle)
let vcB = searchStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "B") as! ViewControllerB // or the name of your `UIViewController`
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcB, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you connect segues by interfece builder, you have to specify the type of segue where you have multiple options: `show`, `present modally` and others. In order to push a controller to the navigation you should select the `show` (or `push` for previous versions of swift) for the type of segue or else it would present the controller modally